# Webservice not working in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, currency, web-services

I configured some currencies in Magento (configuration>general>currencysetup and system>manage currency)

Unfortunately, although i can import manually, it won't update automatically.

Comment: Is your cronjob running?
Do you have any Apache log errors?
Do you have any Magento log errors?

Comment: Hi Sander, i am completely new to magento... do i need to set a cron? it isn't mentioned anywhere.

and how can i check apache log errors and magento log errors?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: i found another post and there it said that when setting the schedule in magento System → Configuration → Currency Setup tab → Scheduled Import Settings this should work

Comment: to set your cron go via SSH to `crontab -e` and check if it has something like `*/5 * * * * php /home/[domain]/www/cron.php`

Comment: :-) Hi Sander, my hoster also gave me that line... thanks (i have set it in directadmin though.
Unfortunately it seems that currency didn't change, but that might be coincidence so i guess i have to follow it

Comment: I think it works.. the currency has changed so... in magento i can set daily as most frequent... is there a way to do this every hour?

Comment: Hi Carlo, by default it's not possible. Set the import to early in the morning and you should have up to date rates. I've added my comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure your Magento cronjob is running. In `crontab` (or directadmin or any other administrative software) check for a cronjob that looks something like `*/5 * * * * php /home/[domain]/www/cron.php`.

Now in the backend under `System > Configuration > Currency Setup > Scheduled Import Settings` you can set the frequency of the import to either daily, weekly or monthly